# iPhone storage issue

Tags: ios, icloud, photos, storage

My iPhone 12 64GB iOS v16.1.1 keeps running out of space. I've performed all the options in 'Manage Storage', removed all but my essentials apps, pruned messages/ attachments, regularly restart etc. The main culprit is Photos, which accounts for more than half the storage usage. I've enabled 'Optimize iPhone Storage' and sync with iCloud (2TB plan), however the phone doesn't have enough storage to even sync.

My partner's phone is connected to the same iCloud account, however their Photos usage is way lower. I imagine this is because I've taken more photos overall, and the phone retains which device it was originally taken on?

I've considered backing the phone up, and setting it up as new, but thought I might lose unsynced data.

[There's also this solution, but again was concerned about data loss](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/291218/ios-photo-no-longer-optimising-storage)

**What options do I have?**

I really don't want to upgrade yet.

Comment: Definitely sounds like your best approach is to toggle photos, as the linked thing says. Unless you have hundreds of thousands of photos then Optimize iPhone Storage switch in Photos settings should be able to take care of it

Comment: As a side note, it's strongly discouraged to share Apple IDs between people. You can share most data between the devices "formally" without signing into the same account. Won't get into that here though but just a note.